# VS2012 : Error with unit test : Assert::AreEqual( object, object ) didn't work

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I come to you for a strange problem when I use the Visual Studio Native Unit Test on VS 2012.
I've a Coordinates class like that:

```
#ifndef COORDINATES_HPP
#define COORDINATES_HPP

#include <iostream>

namespace Core {
class Coordinates {
public:
    Coordinates();
    Coordinates( int x, int y );
    Coordinates( const Coordinates &copy );
    ~Coordinates();

    void operator=( Coordinates coordinates );
    void operator+=( Coordinates coordinates );
    void operator-=( Coordinates coordinates );
    Coordinates operator+( Coordinates coordinates );
    Coordinates operator-( Coordinates coordinates );
    bool operator==( Coordinates coordinates );
    bool operator!=( Coordinates coordinates );

    int getX() const { return m_x; }
    int getY() const { return m_y; }
    void setX( const int &val ) { m_x = val; }
    void setY( const int &val ) { m_y = val; }

protected:
    int m_x, m_y;
};
}
```

So the problem appear when I use :
    Assert::AreEqual( Coordinates(0,0), Coordinates(0,0) );

The error sended is :
Error   1   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Core::Coordinates' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\unittest\include\cppunittestassert.h 129 1   UnitTest1

Do you have an idea for fix that?

PS: Sorry for my english, is not my native language.

Answer (score 20):

The error received after creating your assignment operator, ie

> Error 1   error C2338: Test writer must define specialization of ToString for your class class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::ToString(const class Core::Coordinates &).

is related to needing to provide a way for the unit tests to print out the values it expected and received. You do this by creating a template specialization of the ToString function in the `Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework` namespace. For example:

```
namespace Microsoft{
    namespace VisualStudio {
        namespace CppUnitTestFramework {

            template<>
            static std::wstring ToString<Coordinates>(const Coordinates  & coord) {
                return L"Some string representing coordinate.";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

After that, the unit tests should run.

Comment: Why did you do a template function specialization? Why not just use a function overload? What's the point in this case?

Comment: I couldn't tell you. My knowledge of C++ was worse back in 2014 and I've not really touched Visual Studio since then. It may be that simple overload would work.

Comment: In this context, they both work. I've just not seen anyone use a specialized function template before. Hadn't even realized that they were possible. But it was interesting looking it up. There are a few unexpected gotchas with them though, which is why they aren't used a lot.

Comment: It's 2019, and this still works for Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: it still works in VS2022, and the overloaded function can be optionally declared in the global namespace (not in `Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework`) to save some keyboard strokes :)

Answer (score 1):

Given the error message, you might try making your operator== more const friendly:

```
bool operator==( const Coordinates coordinates ) const;
```

Comment: Error 1 error C2338: Test writer must define specialization of ToString<const Q& q> for your class class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > __cdecl Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::ToString<class Core::Coordinates>(const class Core::Coordinates &). c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\unittest\include\cppunittestassert.h 66 1 UnitTest1

Comment: Just to add to that, for any method/function/operator overload that isn't changing the current object and any parameter that you aren't intending to change should be marked with a const.

Comment: And unless there is a reason to create a copy, go with `bool operator == (const Coordinates & coordinates) const`

Comment: 'bool operator==( const Coordinates &coordinates ) const;' I try this but I have the same error.