# Assert::AreSame() is failing for custom class with overloaded & operator

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

Why is `Assert::AreSame()` failing?

C++ class to be tested:

```
template <typename T>
class XPtr
{
private:
    T* p;
public:
    XPtr(T* ptr) {
        p = ptr;
    }

    XPtr(const XPtr& ptr) {
        p = ptr.p;
    }

    T* operator&() {
        return p;
    }

    // The following declaration compiles but still 
    // is it the correct way of declaring friend function?
    template<typename T>
    friend std::wstring getString(const XPtr<T>& p); 
};

template<typename T>
std::wstring getString(const XPtr<T>& p) {
    std::wstringstream ss;
    ss << L"{" << p.p;
    if (p.p != 0) { ss << L"," << *p.p; }
    ss << L"}";
    return ss.str();
}
```

Native C++ Unit Test is as follows:

```
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace Microsoft {
    namespace VisualStudio {
        namespace CppUnitTestFramework {
            //Actually I would like to specialize for XPtr<T> instead of XPtr<int>, 
            //how to do it?
            template<>
            static std::wstring ToString<XPtr<int> >(const class XPtr<int> & t) 
            { return getString<int>(t); }
        }
    }
}

namespace TestRCPtr1
{       
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod6)
        {
            XPtr<int> p1(new int(1));
            XPtr<int> p2(p1); 
            Assert::AreEqual(&p1, &p2); // Test passes
            Assert::AreSame(p1, p2);    // Test fails, see below for error message
        }
    };
}
```

> Result Message: Assert failed. Expected:<{000000001BE465D0,1}> Actual:<{000000001BE465D0,1}>

Question 1: As per my understanding `Assert::AreSame()` should compare with logic `&p1==&p2` and pass successfully. What is going wrong here?

Question 2: How to specialize `Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::ToString()` (see at top of unit test code) for `XPtr<T>` instead of `XPtr<int>` ?

Comment: It's possible `Assert::AreSame` uses [`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) or similar to bypass the overloaded `operator&`. You can likely step into the implementation under debugger, and find out.

Comment: What is this `ToString` that you want to specialized? No such name is declared in the code you've shown. The specialization you do show should fail to compile, for lack of the primary template.

Comment: Actually its `Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::ToString()` (see it at top of unit test code), I need to specialize it in order for the `Assert::AreSame()` to compile. I did it based on stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312325/vs2012-error-with-unit-test-assertareequal-object-object-didnt-work

Comment: Because `p1` and `p2` aren't the same object. Why do you think it should pass?

Comment: Try providing an overload, like this: `template<typename T> std::wstring ToString<XPtr<T> >(const class XPtr<T> & t) {...}`

Comment: If we look into the code of CppUnitTestAssert.h then it is using & operator to get the address. 
`template<typename T> static void AreSame(const T& expected, const T& actual, ...)
{
    FailOnCondition(&expected == &actual, ...);
}`
Since it is overloaded and returns the same address for T* p I am assuming it should pass.

Comment: @MandeepSingh, you should pay more attention to the first comment. Page that `std::addressof` link refers explains how it is implemented.

Comment: @RealFresh if `AreSame` is using `std::addressof` then its checking assertion correctly and it should fail. Just that in code of `AreSame` I see that it is calling `FailOnCondition(&expected == &actual, ..` and not using `std::addressof`. If someone can throw some light on it then I think we can accept that answer.