# Compare enum types

Tags: c++, visual-studio, enums, microsoft-cpp-unit-test

I am implementing some unit test using cpp unit test framework for visual studio. I want to be able to compare enums in the test but there is always an error that keeps showing up.

This is the code that causes me the error.

```
ClauseEntities ent1 = varMap.at("a");
ClauseEntities ent2 = varMap.at("v");

Assert::AreEqual(ent1, ASSIGN_STATEMENT);
Assert::AreEqual(ent1, VARIABLE);
```

ent1 is a enum state and ASSIGN_STATEMENT is also an enum state from the same enum.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2338   Test writer must define specialization of ToString<const Q& q> 
for your class class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct 
std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > __cdecl 
Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::ToString<enum ClauseEntities>
(const enum ClauseEntities &).  
UnitTesting C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\UnitTest\include\CppUnitTestAssert.h 66
```

Not sure how i am supposed to create a template specialisation for to string of enums..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS2012 : Error with unit test : Assert::AreEqual( object, object ) didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312325/vs2012-error-with-unit-test-assertareequal-object-object-didnt-work)

Comment: I can't believe this [isn't even covered in Microsoft's own tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-microsoft-test-framework-for-cpp?view=vs-2019) on setting up its unit testing framework. I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple

```cpp
namespace Microsoft {
namespace VisualStudio {
namespace CppUnitTestFramework { // not sure if namespaces are actually needed

std::wstring ToString(ClauseEntities value)
{
    switch (value) {
    case ClauseEntities::ValueA: return L"ValueA"; //assuming that you are using enum class
    case ClauseEntities::ValueB: return L"ValueB";
    }

    return std::to_wstring(static_cast<int>(value));
}

} // namespace CppUnitTestFramework 
} // namespace VisualStudio
} // namespace Microsoft
```

Comment: What if the things being compared are objects of a custom type and not an enum? I've tried to get this to work all day but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 3):

I have never used microsoft cpp unit tests, but from the error message and experience with gtests I think you have to add a method `ToString` for your enum class. (My guess is) It is because if the Assert fails, both arguments are printed to some output using `ToString` method.

At the end of [this](https://putridparrot.com/blog/unit-testing-native-c-code-using-visual-studio/) article similar problem is solved.